# React page with multiple components of the same type. Show more of same components on button click, prevent re-rendering in original set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react summary page which displays line graphs through use of a ReportProgressSummary component.

On initial load a data set is mapped to display multiple of these components.

On clicking the expand button, a further, larger set of these components is rendered below. My issue is that the initial components also re-render.

The component shows a line graph rendering dynamically so the re-renders are very obvious. Is there a way I can prevent the re-render of the initial components?

I am thinking that I need to record the percentage value reached within the ReportProgressSummary component, and be able to test against its final value to see if a re-render is necessary... maybe using useRef(), but I'm not quite sure how...

For example, if the component's percentage variable has already achieved the passed in 'result' value, then it would not be required to render again.

ReportProgressSummary Component:

```
const ReportProgressSummary = ({result, title}) => {
    const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0);
    let timer = React.useRef();

    useEffect( () => {
        let newPercent = percent + 1;
        if (newPercent > result) {
            clearTimeout(timer.current);
            return;
        }
        timer.current = setTimeout(() => setPercent(newPercent), 1);
    }, [percent]);

    return (
        <ContainerStyled>
            <ChartContainerStyled>
                <ChartTitleStyled>{title}</ChartTitleStyled>
                <CheckboxStyled type="checkbox" />
            </ChartContainerStyled>
            <ChartContainerStyled>
                <LineContainerStyled>
                    <Line trailWidth="2" trailColor="red" strokeWidth="4" strokeColor="green" percent={percent}/>
                </LineContainerStyled>
                <h6>{percent}%</h6>
            </ChartContainerStyled>
        </ContainerStyled>
    )
};

export default ReportProgressSummary;
```

Summary Component:

```
const Summary = () => {
    const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("expand");

    const onButtonClick = () => {
        setExpand(!expand);
        if(!expand) setButtonText("hide");
        else setButtonText("expand");
    };

    return (
        <div className="test">
            <PageTitle title="System Overview"/>
            <ContainerStyled>
            {
                selectedRules.map(rule => {
                    return <ReportProgressSummary result={rule.percentage} title={rule.name} key={shortid.generate()}/>
                })
            }
            </ContainerStyled>

            <ButtonStyled onClick={() => onButtonClick()}>{buttonText}</ButtonStyled>
            {
                expand &&
                <ContainerStyled>
                    {
                        nonSelectedRules.map(rule => {
                            return <ReportProgressSummary result={rule.percentage} title={rule.name} key={shortid.generate()}/>
                        })
                    }
                </ContainerStyled>
            }
        </div>
    )
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: On every render of `Summary`, the value of the `key` attribute will be a new randomly generated `shortid`. This will tell React to re-render the resulting components. Find another way to make your keys unique without calling `shortid.generate()` on every render.

Comment: Great, that worked - thanks! As a quick test I just switched the key out to be the array index, but I know that's not recommended. Is there a best practice for keys you could recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure what the industry best-practice is. I usually use the index plus some text identifier unique to the component. In this case, I might use `selected-rules-rpg-${index}`. But if the component gets reused, you could also generate a single `shortid` outside of the component definition, so it gets generated once per instance, and use that together with the index. Outside `Summary`: `const randId = shortid.generate()`. Within, `Summary`, for the list: `selected-rules-rpg-${index}-${randId}`

Comment: I'm just going to rewrite this an an answer to the question in case someone else in the community has this same issue.

Comment: I'm also adding some updates to my comment above about ids from some research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is how you are setting the `key` attribute on the mapped components:

```
key={shortid.generate()}
```

Every time the `Summary` component is rendered, the values of the keys will be a new unique `shortid`. React discerns will then rerender that component even if none of the props have changed.

Keys should be as unique as necessary, but they should not be changed within a map unless the Component should be rerendered (keep this in mind in case you need to force a rerender of a Component). In fact, [they only need to be unique among their siblings](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings)

Moreover, there are circumstances where using the `index` is perfectly safe (see [Update: Exception from the Rule](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318))